# Is there a way of adding horizontal rulers between classes and methods on VS Code, like IntelliJ?

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

> [I've created a feature request based on this in VS Code's repository on Github.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113458)

I've been using IntelliJ in some of my jobs and this feature of a horizontal ruler between classes and methods is really neat in my opinion, it helps visually finding boundaries more quickly in the code.

Is there a way of doing that in VS Code? Would it be possible to do it by, for example, adding a ruler above a regex for `class` or a function?

[image: An example of horizontal rulers between methods. It doesn't work properly in Dart, but it does in Java.]

The example above shows some code in Dart. The feature doesn't work 100% in Dart, but it does in Java.

Comment: This is Intellij Built-in feature. As of now, VSCode has not such feature

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it be possible to do it by, for example, adding a ruler above a regex for `class` or a function?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can as well post a feature-request on the vscode's github page to see if such thing is already available

Comment: Done. I added the link to the new feature request.

Comment: @dm_tr the feature request was well received. VS Code devs have labeled it a candidate feature for their backlog. It needs 20 votes by the community to enter their backlog.

Comment: Such a great thing! I'll vote it too